# Is it possible to transfer "L13 Projects" extension workspaces/favorites projects between profiles VSCode?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I use L13 Projects (L13RARY.l13-projects) VScode extension to manage my projects. Since VScode has introduced profiles, and I created couple profiles, after some time, my workspaces have been "desynchronized", because I added new projects in one profile, then I added new projects in another profile and so on...

Is there a way to easy synchronize projects between my VScode profiles?

I tried to export extension settings, but they don't contain projects/workspaces.